# How to apply CNN algorithm in python for non image dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset in the below format

feature1 feature2   feature 3 ....... feature 8000 decision.
dataset size is (900*8000) and every column's value is either 0 or 1 (in binary) this is basically an android malware dataset of permissions and I need to apply CNN using TensorFlow for this dataset.
I applied to cifar dataset but not getting how to use the same algo for this dataset as there are no images.
what to change in code and what will be the value of activation, input_shape, conv2D etc

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
keras.__version__
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer',
               'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i][0]])
plt.show()
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
                    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0.5, 1])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
print(test_acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have 900 samples in the dataset, each of them having 8000 features. You could reshape the 1-D tensor of 8000 values to, let's say, "an image" of shape (80, 100). I'm not sure if CNN is the best type of neural network for these values. You'll see.
Also, 900 samples might not be enough to train a neural network properly. It depends on the complexity of the problem. You'll need a shallow architecture, otherwise, it's going to overfit.